# Vite: Could not resolve entry module (index.html)

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, openshift

I am new to Openshift 3.11 deployment, I created a Multistage Dockerfile for a React application, the  build want correctly on my local machine, but when I run on the openshift cluster I get the error below:

```
> kncare-ui@0.1.0 build
> tsc && vite build

vite v2.9.9 building for production...
✓ 0 modules transformed.
Could not resolve entry module (index.html).
error during build:
Error: Could not resolve entry module (index.html).
    at error (/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:198:30)
    at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22680:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
error: build error: running 'npm run build' failed with exit code 1
```

and this is my Dockefile

```
FROM node:16.14.2-alpine as build-stage      
RUN mkdir -p /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN chmod -R 777 /app/
COPY package*.json /app/
COPY tsconfig.json /app/
COPY tsconfig.node.json /app/
RUN npm ci
COPY ./ /app/
RUN npm run build

FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged 
#FROM bitnami/nginx:latest
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
#CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 20):

Vite uses an html page as an entry point by default. So you either need to create one or if you don't have an html page, you can use it in "library mode".

https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode

From the docs:

```
// vite.config.js
const path = require('path')
const { defineConfig } = require('vite')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib/main.js'),
      name: 'MyLib',
      fileName: (format) => `my-lib.${format}.js`
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell it where the html page is and not use library mode? For example if index.html is inside a folder like /public/index.html

Comment: You're just changing your main entry file. Use the example in their docs for multipage app and just ignore the nested line: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app

Comment: In the end I found the best solution was to move my index.html file to the root as per this Issue https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/798

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue because of `.dockerignore`. Make sure your `index.html` not ignored.
In case if you ignoring everything (`**`) you can add `!index.html` to the next line and try.